# Changing the shell (using chsh) via the command line in a script

Tags: linux, shell

In a startup script that sets up a machine, I want to run

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

However, this asks for the user's password. How do I pass in the password as a parameter? Or if I have sudo power, can I somehow bypass that step? Or alternatively, is there another way to change the default startup shell?

Answer (score 25):

The following prevents locked-down accounts from changing their shells, and selectively lets people use `chsh` themselves WITHOUT sudo or su:

### Simple setup that is still secure:

1. Add this very top of `/etc/pam.d/chsh`:

   ```
   # This allows users of group chsh to change their shells without a password.
   #
   # Per: http://serverfault.com/questions/202468/changing-the-shell-using-chsh-via-the-command-line-in-a-script
   #
   auth       sufficient   pam_wheel.so trust group=chsh
   ```
2. Create the chsh group:

   ```
   groupadd chsh
   ```

### For any user allowed to change their shell:

```
    usermod -a -G chsh username
```

### Money shot:

```
user@host:~$ getent passwd $USER
user:x:1000:1001::/home/user:/bin/bash
user@host:~$ chsh -s `which zsh`
user@host:~$ getent passwd $USER
user:x:1000:1001::/home/user:/usr/bin/zsh
user@host:~$
```

Comment: Working solution, wonder that this still not accepted.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the cleanest way to let a user using keypair-only auth change shell without sudo. This pam.d stuff is very interesting!

Answer (score 4):

chsh actually changes the line pertaining to a user in /etc/passwd, though a user can only change his/her own 'line' in /etc/passwd. Hence, if you want to change shell for another user, you need his / her passwd.

If you really want to do it (given the concerns in Lorenzo's post, and possible security concerns) here's how one can do this:

```
#visudo
```

This requires root privileges.

Say you're currently running as "alice" and want to change "bob's" shell without password;

Add to the file:

```
Cmnd_Alias     SHELL = /usr/bin/chsh
Runas_Alias    SH    = Bob
alice          ALL   = (SH) NOPASSWD: SHELL
```

This makes sure 'alice' can run on all hosts as the users in the group SH without a password the group of commands in SHELL.

Probably a bit far fetched to do it this way, but it is possible.

Be sure to read "man sudoers" before changing the sudores file with 'visudo', especially the messages related to security!

Comment: The problem with `sudo` is that it's extremely easy to circumvent and root a system.   It's better to never change `sudoers` unless there is a specific need that cannot be met any other way (setuid/setgid executable, group permissions, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the username; doing this via `sudo` (or by root) will allow you to set a user's password/shell without being asked the old password. Please check `man chsh` for further information.

Now my question is: why would you want to do that? If it's a set-up script, shouldn't you just change the users' shell at creation time (i.e. when launching `adduser`)? If you're cloning a system remotely, shouldn't you change it in `/etc/passwd` first? I see no reasons for doing it via a script, unless you automated the whole installation process and the selection of shells to be installed comes after the creation of the first user.

Comment: It's for an ec2 machine (the script I run right after the machine starts up). I want to change the default starting shell. Doing "sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh user_name" doesn't work either (still asks for the user's password)

Comment: try using a script, and use `#!/usr/bin/sudo -s` (shebang line). Also, you sure zsh is in /bin and not, perhaps, in /usr/bin? (just checking, I'm not familiar with ec2)

Comment: This answer is incomplete because it assumes `sudo` permission.  See mine for a different approach that doesn't require `sudo` for the average user.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh`, then:

1. exit for server
2. restart terminal
3. log into server, and check by `echo $SHELL` – in successful case it changed :)

Comment: This will actually set zsh as default terminal for the root user.

Comment: @lcguida right.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can change the user's shell in the `/etc/password` file, possibly by using the `passwd` command. I haven't read through it yet but this may be useful: [UNIX shell differences and how to change your shell](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/shell-differences/).

Comment: The commands are `chsh` or `usermod`.  Never edit the `passwd` file directly, always use the `vipw` command for that.